# How to keep checking a list for items

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I want to check a python list for items. If an item is there, do something with it. For example:

- Time 0: No items - do nothing
- Time 1: 1 item added - remove item to do something with it
- Time 2: 0 item in list - do nothing
- Time 3: 2 items added - remove 1 item to do something with it. 1 item left.
- Time 4: 1 item added (already 1 item from before) - Total 2 items. Remove 1 item to do something with it. 1 item left.
- Time 5: 0 item added (already 1 item in list) - remove item to do something with it.
- To inifinity

I was thinking about pipes and multiprocessing, but whats the best way? Here's some pseudo code:

`arr = []
<code to read from a datastream and add interesting things to arr>
when(len(arr) > 0):
    item = arr.pop()
    print(item)`

Comment: By your idea there will be code which puts stuff into the list. Why not extend that code to also do the printing?

Comment: Try using queues instead of arrays. Setup 1 process that works as "listener" and check if there is something in queue, if so pick it and do the stuff.

Comment: @Yunnosch for efficiency purposes I don't want to do both linearly. The print is just pseudo code, but assume its some computationally intensive but not time-critical task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you are referring to is a `Producer-Consumer` Problem. There are several ways of solving it using multiple threads or multiple processes and using different datastructures. But, the most common is a queue.

I am just sharing one reference implementation of Producer-Consumer in Python. You can take this as a reference and improvise on it.

https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2013/10/producer-consumer-problem-in-python/